# Trying to disable a button using Angular's ng-disable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-scope

I have this in my angular code:

```
$scope.Disable = false;

$scope.SetDisable = function (Number) {
    if (Number.length < 4) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }


};

$scope.$watch("Admin.UserName", function () {
    $scope.Disable = $scope.SetDisable($scope.Admin.UserName.length);
});
```

And this code in my view:

```
<input id="Submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Login" ng-disabled="Disable" />
```

Notice that ever i change the default value of `$scipe.Disable` to `true` and turn the other lines of code in my Angular script to comment, the button is still enabled.

If i change the code in my View to:

```
<input id="Submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Login" ng-disabled="true" />
```

(ng-disabled="**true**")

The button is disabled.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please also provide a plunker snippet?

Comment: What is the length of `$scope.Admin.UserName`?

Comment: I am suspecting you are not specifying the ngController to control `<input id="Submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Login" ng-disabled="Disable" />` see [ngController usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **ng-change** instead of $watch e.g.

```
$scope.myChange = function (nu) {

  if (nu.length < 4) {
      $scope.Disable = false;
  }
  else {
      $scope.Disable = true;
  }
};
```

see this link: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/m5TUzC35gg8EuApVHcO0?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This may caused by Angular [scope inheritance feature](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes), you could overcome this issue by two approaches:

1. use `controller as` syntax:

   ```
   angular.controller('formController', function(){
       this.Disabled = false;
   })

   <div ng-controller="formController as ctrl">
       <input ng-disabled="ctrl.Disabled">
   </div>
   ```
2. use a reference variable instead of a primitive variable

   ```
   $scope.Disabled = { value: false }

   <input ng-disabled="Disabled.value">
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that within the $watch() function you pass the length of the string instead of the string when call the function SetDisable() and in this function you use the length again in the if condition.

**HTML**:

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="mainController">
    <div>
      <label>UserName:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="UserName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
      <hr>
      <input id="Submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Login" ng-disabled="Disable" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS**:

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('mainController', mainController);

mainController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function mainController($scope) {
  $scope.Disable = false;

  var SetDisable = function (name) {
      if (name.length < 4) {
          return false;
      } else {
          return true;
      }
  }  

  $scope.$watch('UserName', function() {
    $scope.Disable = SetDisable($scope.UserName);
  })

}
```

I made a working example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GomYGq?editors=101